# php timestamp function needed

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689843/formatting-a-timestamp)

I require a php function that returns the date in the format in the same format as mySQL function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (i.e like this--> 2011-08-10 17:17:23).

Wondering if there's anything available

Answer (score 10):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

will do the job.

Comment: Hmm; why the random community wiki?!

Comment: @Tomalak because it's very trivial - I was just too lazy to look for the appropriate duplicate

Comment: @Tomalak yeah. Related:  [Introduce a  "general reference" close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043) you're welcome to give that a +1 if you agree :)

Comment: @Pekka: I already did ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for this.

```
// example result 2010-08-12 22:30:45
$mysqlTime = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Also if you want to get a MySQL date as a timestamp for use in php functions you can use MySQL's [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function

Comment: `date()` by default returns current time, so the call to `time()` is redundant here.

Comment: That's true, just demonstrating that you can pass in a second argument.

Comment: Cool. Passing a non-trivial argument would be more interesting though IMHO ;)